# Sort NSArray having NSData array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsarray

i have this nsarray having images data in it images setting dynamically in array but i want to filter data if there is any nil nsdata i dont want it inside my nsarray how can i sort this array. here is my code.

```
NSData* imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"profileImg"];
    NSData* imageData1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"profileImg1"];
    NSData* imageData2 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"profileImg2"];
    NSData* imageData3 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"profileImg3"];
    NSData* imageData4 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"profileImg4"];
    NSData* imageData5 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"profileImg5"];




    self.pageImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                           [UIImage imageWithData:imageData],
                                           [UIImage imageWithData:imageData1],
                                           [UIImage imageWithData:imageData2],
                                           [UIImage imageWithData:imageData3],
                                           [UIImage imageWithData:imageData4],
                                           [UIImage imageWithData:imageData5],nil];
```

Comment: There can't be `nil` objects in an `NSArray`. If, for example, `imageData1` is `nil`, the array will only contain `imageData` and no other images.

Comment: So if i put some other dummy pic instead of nil so will it work then?? I mean how can i apply if statement on is image is dummy then DONOT add is in nsaray!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would take a completely different approach. The problem is that `arrayWithObjects:` stops when it encounters a `nil`. If, for example, `imageData1` is `nil`, your array will only have one image - `imageData`.

A better way would be to check each one for `nil`. Only add the non-nil images.

```
NSArray *keys = @[ @"profileImg", @"profileImg1", @"profileImg2", @"profileImg3", @"profileImg4", @"profileImg5" ];
NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *key in keys) {
    NSData* imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:key];
    if (imageData) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        if (image) {
            [images addObject:image];
        }
    }
}

self.pageImages = [images copy];
```

Comment: triend this one but app crashes and output "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFData _isDecompressing]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1567164a0'"

Answer (score 1):

You can directly check whether the object at that index is nil.

```
NSMutableArray * finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i< pageImages.count; i++) {
    if (pageImages[i]){
        UIImage * temp = [pageImages objectAtIndex:i];
        [finalArray addObject:temp];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying i actually want to store sorted data inside the same self.pageImages

Comment: i actually want to exclude all the images with nill data or no images in it out of my nsarray

Comment: Yes, that's what I am saying . take the finalArray and store in pageImages

Comment: Add after for loop -    pageImages = finalArray ;

Comment: i did that but still no luck :(

Comment: NSMutableArray * finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i< self.pageImages.count; i++) {
        if (self.pageImages[i]){
            UIImage * temp = [self.pageImages objectAtIndex:i];
            [finalArray addObject:temp];
        }
    }
    self.pageImages = finalArray ;

Comment: What is the result . Can you state what is happening

Comment: Are the images  available in Project ? (All or Some )

Comment: i have 3 images set imagedata of 0,3 and 4 and imagedata 1,2 and 5 are nil so it is only showing image first image which is on "0" not going further to 3 and 4

Comment: And what if you directly print the pageImages. Does it prints nil for nil data? Also what is the array count?

Comment: images : (
    "<UIImage: 0x13469cf00>, {320, 320}"
)